# Setting a node in a treeview to checked programmatically returns System.StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

I am trying to not allow multiple nodes to be checked in a tree view.

I have found the `before_check` event handler so that I can just uncheck all other nodes before the one the user checks is checked.

I have tried console writing the name of the nodes, just to see if I have the right layer of nodes, that all works fine.

```
private void TreeView1_BeforeCheck(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (TreeNode node in treeView1.nodes)
    {
        if (treeView1.Nodes != null)
        {
            node.Checked = false;
            //Console.WriteLine(node.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when im trying to set the node to checked. It just gives `System.StackOverflowException` whenever I press on a checkbox.

Comment: That would be because `node.Checked = false` triggers another `TreeView1_BeforeCheck`, and the endless loop of triggering is started.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply, what would you suggest I do instead?

Comment: Use the `TreeViewCancelEventArgs e` argument and `object sender` to inspect only the object under change and abort the operation if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `TreeViewCancelEventArgs.Action` value to only clear checkboxes when the event was triggered by user activity.

Enumerate nodes using a recursive method. Don't uncheck the one node that is to be checked.

```
private void UncheckNodesExcept(TreeNode root, TreeNode except)
{
    // Clear checkbox unless it is the one we don't want to clear
    if(root != except)
    {
        root.Checked = false;
    }

    // Recurse over childs
    foreach(TreeNode child in root.Nodes)
    {
        UncheckNodesExcept(child, except);
    }
}

private void treeView1_BeforeCheck(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
    TreeView treeView = sender as TreeView;

    // Only if action was triggered by user
    if (e.Action == TreeViewAction.ByKeyboard || e.Action == TreeViewAction.ByMouse)
    {
        foreach(TreeNode node in treeView.Nodes)
        {
            UncheckNodesExcept(node, e.Node);
        }
    }
}
```